# Neumann KM 183 Stereo Pair

Tags: neumann, omni, ambience, room, stereo

Just wondering if anyone has had any experience of using these for recording outdoor atmos and quiet room tones?
I would like a pair of omnis to record open outdoor spaces and from what I understand are also good for quiet room tones (or air) as omnis have low noise. Would like to know how these compare to the Schoeps CMC with omni capsule or the Sennheiser 8000 series omnis.
Cheers.

Comment: Thing is, I like the idea of getting the Neumann's but I don't want to be wishing I'd spent a bit more and went with Schoeps or Senn - particularly ones with exchangeable capsules as I would like a good MS set up eventually too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick room tone recording inside a playback/conference room I made just now with the KM183:

http://we.tl/KRqYmKPAch
(this is the original 96 kHz 24bit wav file) (re-uploaded Feb. 25th)

Neumann KM183 spaced omni pair, about 1m apart, into a Sound Devices 788t, 60 dB of gain. No filtering, no editing.

The background SPL was 31.0 dBA (measured).

The buzz you hear is a pair of Genelec subwoofers that is switched on.

At the moment, I don't have any quiet outdoor atmos on hand. Maybe I'll get around to it later.

Comment: Thanks so much. To me it sounds great, way less noise than the ones I use from my library.  Definitely tempted. Don't worry about the outdoor ambience, it was only if you had one already. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have a pair, so far I'm very pleased with them. I'll record some room tone and put it here so you can have a listen.

Comment: an quiet outdoor atmos recordings would be great to hear too if you have any at hand

Answer (score 0):

Hi

Neumann is always great, they are my favorite! Very good sound quality, very good signal to noise floor-difference and also robust design and very reliable. I work since many years with the KM140 and the figure-8 AK20 as an MS set. I made recording all over the world from hot places and icecold wintermountains. Never had any problems.
I think the KM184 (cardiodid one) is one of the most flexiblest microphones. Other than sound recorders or a pro tools system, good quality microphones keeps it's price and if you want to sell it once, you will not loos lot's of money if the mic is still fine. For a sound recorder you get almost nothing after some years.
Also neumann is great with the price, you can purchase 2 neumann microphones from the KM-Series for the price from one high-quality schoeps mic. And also for loud level are the neumann great. Others like the schoeps (they are great too, but much more expansiv) get harsh and sharp.

Best

Guido